# could not convert string to float error when loading excel files (python)

Tags: python, excel, import

I am trying to load a couple of excel files (.xlsx) into python, which are all stored in the same folder. I get the error 'could not convert string to float' when I am using my code below:

```
import numpy as np
import glob


data_list = []

filenames = glob.glob('*.xlsx')

for fname in filenames:
    data = np.loadtxt(filenames)
    data_list.append(data)
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`np.loadtxt` can't read excel file, you can use `Pandas` instead:

```
# Python env: pip install pandas
# Miniconda env: conda install pandas
import pandas as pd
import glob

data_list = []

filenames = glob.glob('*.xlsx')

for fname in filenames:
    data = pd.read_excel(fname)  # <- HERE fname, not filenames
    data_list.append(data.to_numpy())
```